# How to Display Post in Chronological Order using WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to reverse the chronological order of posts so that the order goes from first post to last?

I have found one of the answers for this question:
*"Their is no way to change the order to chronological unless you want to change the date on all your posts, and that is a bad thing since any post that has been picked up by the search engines would then return a 404 file not found error if you change the dates on them."*

Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a WordPress expert.

I googled and found [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/reverse-chronological-order-of-posts) and [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/chronological-order) and [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-older-post-show-first) and [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-order-of-posts-oldest-first).

I think it's a good idea if you post that question on [WordPress answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

There are many results for the search query: "*change wordpress chronological*" and it seems possible and easy.

Your second question: *Is it a good idea to do so?* I really don't know, I'm not a wordpress expert, maybe others can answer that question.

**EDIT**

Have you watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yna_z2feTqM)? It's about [Post Types Order](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/), also check the example of usage video on their page.

Also take a look at [WordPress plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=posts%20order&sort=)

Comment: I have tried read the half of links you sent before. They were not helpful. why? because there was no "step by step" explanation, or some cases were for the concrete page and concrete .php files which i had not. thanks for help though.

Comment: @Gio please read my edit